# 「～てます」 as an adjective

Tags: verbs, adjectives

In an email, I came across

> 搭載されてます機能。。。

I understand how 「～ています」can get shortened to 「～てます」, but I thought this was informal (hence, contradicting the need for the 「～ます」 ending.

Also, I found it strange to be using a verb with a 「～ます」 ending as an adjective. What are the rules/nuances of using 「～ます」 like this?

Comment: I can't provide any sources, but the expression does not sound like a proper Japanese (my mother tongue). The use of "です" "ます" in the 連体形 is rather rare. I can only come up with "搭載されております機能", a very polite expression, perhaps used by a salesperson to their customers. "搭載されている機能は次のとおりです" (the functions equipped are as follows) does not sound rude at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 搭載されてます機能

If this was in a formal business email, I would say it's grammatical but overly casual. As you well know, the ています-to-てます-conversion is very common in casual and colloquial Japanese, but that's not something you can use in a business email.

They should have wrote in one of the followings ways:

> - 搭載されています機能
> - 搭載されております機能 (using humble おる)
> - 搭載されている機能

As you can see, using ます to modify the following noun like this is not uncommon.

That said, the last one is universally valid, and I personally prefer it even in a formal email. There is no need to use 丁寧語 there, and I feel that using the first form too much may leave an obsequious impression on people.

Of course you can safely say "搭載されてる機能" in a casual situation.